# How did Doctor Strange know where Wanda was?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

Towards the end of *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*,

> after dreamwalking into ponytail Doctor Strange

Doctor Strange uses the slingy to make a portal, and we can see from the portal that there's an icy mountain.

[image]

Then in the next shot, we see that he's heading towards

> Mount Wundagore

However, at this point in the story, he shouldn't know that

> Sara destroyed the Darkhold and that Wong took Wanda to Mount Wundagore

as he's been with America the entire time, and hasn't gone back to his own world. The last time he saw Wanda, she was at

> Kamar Taj

How did he know where she was?

Comment: Wong got him a _Where's Wanda?_ book for Christmas; turned out it was actually a useful magical artefact, not just a fun puzzle diversion.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite you manage to come up with some of the most highly up voted and amusing comments. ;)

Comment: And _yet_ there's no Class Clown badge on Stack Exchange. It's almost as if they don't want to encourage this sort of incessant inane behaviour!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Strange peers into the multiverse first to find America, he doesn't seem to be looking for *his* universe but rather the one where America is at that time. Presumably when doing this he also pinpoints where she is in that universe as well. He does see her in it after all.

[image: dr strange surrounded by various glowing red orbs, looking for one with America Chavez inside]